# Heat Equation with insulated ends

Tags: differential-equations, heat-equation

I have a problem with Heat Equation.Imagine this.We have this equation ----> ut=uxx with boundary conditions u(0,t)=0 u(25,t)=0 and initial condition u(x,0)=x.
Find u(x,t) and make the Plot ( doesnt matter and what dimensions)
I've written this on code :

```
heqn = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
bc = {u[0, t] == 0, u[25, t] == 0};

ics = u[x, 0] == x ;

sol = DSolve[{heqn, bc, ics}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

What am I doing wrong? It says that equation or list of equations expected instead of heqn in the first argument {heqn,bcs,ics}
Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: Which version are you usng? It works like a charm in version 12.0. Btw.: These are not the boundary conditions of insulated ends; those would be `bc = {D[u[x, t], x] == 0 /. {x -> 0}, D[u[x, t], x] == 0 /. {x -> 25}}`.

Comment: Im using 11.2.Well they gave me this information : u(0,t)=0 u(25,t)=0 and u(x,0)=x

Comment: "Insulated ends" doesn't correspond to your code {u[0, t] == 0, u[25, t] == 0} (this note has nothing to do with Mathematica)

Comment: Could you be more specific? I'm new in Mathematica and trying to self - learn it.Thank you tho for your reply.

Comment: Don't know about "insulated ends". But if you change the initial conditions to `ics = u[x, 0] == x (25 - x)` there is no conflict between ics and bcs anymore and Mathematica 12 is able to solve..

Comment: Unfortunately still the same result in 11.2

Comment: *Update* It kinda works but it  gives me out exactly this ------->DSolve[{heqn, bcs, ics}, u[x, t], {x, t}] while i guess it should have given me the sum up .

Comment: as everyone is saying, it works on V 12.1. You can try it online if you do not have V 12.1